# Яке походження слова Івасик-Телесик?

Tags: етимологія

Відомий український казковий герой зветься Івасик-**Телесик**.
Якою є етимологія цієї назви?

Усі варіанти, які я бачив, виглядають або занадто натягнутими, або просто бездоказовими. Тому хотілося б дізнатися етимологію, яка **базується на поважних лінґвістичних джерелах**, а не на здогадках.

---

Ось список варіантів, які я бачив, і які мені не подобаються внаслідок своєї бездоказовості:

1. [**Морячок**](https://bytebuster.dreamwidth.org/2245818.html) — (моє власне дослідження, виглядає дещо натягнутим):

   > Грецькою слово «море» — [`θάλασσα`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B8%CE%AC%CE%BB%CE%B1%CF%83%CF%83%CE%B1), читається `[tʰá-las-sa]`.
   >   Wiktionary і інші словники кажуть, що:
   >   «Etymology: Possibly from `ἅλς` (`háls`, “salt”). Might be from Pre-Greek.»
   >   Тайське слово ทะเล `[tʰáʔ leː]` «море» має кхмерське походження. Див., наприклад, відоме озеро в Камбоджі, *Тон-ле-сап*.
2. [**Телепень**](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/480034-skazka-pro-ivasika-telesika-chto-oznachaet-slovo-telesik.html) — внаслідок народження із дерев'яної чурки, у деяких варіантах казки
3. Той, хто носить [**бриль**](http://ua-mova.livejournal.com/157000.html), солом'яний капелюх (неясно, чи носив він такого капелюха)
4. [**Таліесін**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taliesin) — від кельтського/валлійського імені¹
5. Той, хто пасе [**теля**](http://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/33196.html) —  (не доведено, що він когось пас у казці)

---

¹ Таку думку обстоює, наприклад, Олег Гуцуляк у статті [Кельтський слід в історії слов'ян](http://www.academia.edu/191201/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B4_%D0%B2_%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%97_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD_%D0%95%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81_%D1%96_%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0._-_2015-2016._-_%D0%A1._119-131).

Comment: в мене є два кандидати на братів телесика  [_син теслі_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus) та [англійський хлопчина](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Thumb) зі схожими рисами. На жаль, здогадку про те, що образ Телесика являє собою певну суперпозицію цих запозичень, я перевірити не в змозі :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Марія Редьква, кандидат філологічних наук, викладач кафедри філософії, суспільних дисциплін та іноземних мов Тернопільського державного медичного університету ім. І. Я. Горбачевського, у своїй статті [СЕМАНТИКО-ФУНКЦІОНАЛЬНЕ ЗНАЧЕННЯ КАЗКОВИХ АНТРОПОНІМІВ (НА ПРИКЛАДІ ВАРІАНТІВ НАЗИВАННЯ ТЕЛЕСИКА В УКРАЇНСЬКІЙ НАРОДНІЙ ЧАРІВНІЙ КАЗЦІ)](http://www.nbuv.gov.ua/old_jrn/Soc_Gum/Nz/2011_95_2/statti/80.pdf) висловлює такі гіпотези:

> На перший погляд семантика імені *Телесик* є непрозорою і увиразнює її
>   лише контекст уживання: *И назвали того сина **Телесиком**. От росте той
>   син, та й росте – и такий гарний, що ні здумать, ні згадать – тільки в
>   казці сказать!* [Рудч. (2: 39)]. Проблема витлумачення значення
>   номінатеми зумовлена передовсім нез’ясованістю семантики слова-основи,
>   на базі якого виник онім.
>
> Лексема сучасної української мови, котра
>   вірогідно стала основою для творення номінативної одиниці, це дієслово
>   „**телесуватися**, -уюся, -уєшся, недок., розм. Потикатися, кидатися
>   то в один бік, то в інший…” [4: 1237]. Якщо припустити, що саме ця
>   лексична одиниця могла мотивувати аналізовану номінатему, то семантика
>   імені вказує на таку характеристику персонажа, як рухливість, неспокій
>   тощо.
>
> У територіальних говірках зафіксовано лексему *телесний*, що
>   означає „безтілесний” [13 (2: 283)], від якої теж могло бути утворене
>   найменування, оскільки, за сюжетом, персонажа змальовано деревиною,
>   тобто безтілесним.
>
> У словнику М. Фасмера подано лексеми `тел(ьпень)`,
>   *тельпеш*, що означають „здорова дитина”. І услід за О. Шахматовим етимолог пов’язує їх зі словом *телепень*. Сюди ж учений відносить і
>   лексему `тельпух`, яка має значення „пень, обрубок; неповоротка
>   людина” [17 (4: 40)].
>
> Тому, зважаючи на специфіку образу Телесика,
>   цілком вірогідним видається походження аналізованого казкового
>   антропоніма від наведеного ряду лексем, семантика яких безпосередньо
>   пов’язана зі словами дитина, деревина, пень.

Answer (score 4):

Якщо суто слово, то…

<sub>Етимологічний словник української мови Інституту мовознавства ім. О.О. Потебні НАН України.</sub>

> [**ТЕЛЕ́СИК**](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA) (герой українських казок), **Теле́шик** «тс.»
>
> зменшено-пестливе слово, утворене від [*те́лес*] «стовбур дерева», [*телі́ш*] «колода, шматок дерева»;

> [**ТЕЛІ́Ш**](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81#22789) «колода, шматок дерева», **те́лес** «надземна частина дерева, стовбур», **телє́ш** «колодка на дрова; тулуб (частина тіла)»
>
> - очевидно, повʼязане з *ті́ло*;
> - можливо, так називалася обтесана деревина, яка своєю білизною нагадувала тіло людини, пор. р. [*теле́ш*] «нагота, голизна, оголеність»;
>
> бр. [*цяле́ш*] «кругляк; палиця, колода»;

Answer (score -2):

Мені здається питання, що означає Телесик, дуже просте. Треба тільки уважно подивитися на саму казку і трішки знати українську мову. Щоби зробити з деревини ляльку треба її витесати - обличчя, руки, ноги. Людина яка робила різні вироби з деревини, прикрашала вироби різбою називалась тесляр. Вважаю логічним ляльку хлопчика народ назвав Телесик. Тобто витесаний з деревини, ні намальований, ні злеплений, а тесаний. Тому Івасик-Телесик. Якщо хочете це наш український аналог Буратіно чи Пінокіо. Не знаю хто в кого позичив ідею дерев'яний ляльок, але краще чим Телесик дерев'яну ляльку-хлопчика і назвати неможливо. Ось і вся версія назви.

Comment: Читали запитання? Ось витяг: _Тому хотілося б дізнатися етимологію, яка базується на поважних лінґвістичних джерелах, а не на здогадках._

Comment: Вітаю на Ukrainian Language SE! Додам, що за правилами нашого сайту треба підкріплювати свої висновки посиланнями на джерела, що можуть підтвердити наведені факти та приклади. За цим посиланням можна прочитати [про хороші питання та відповіді](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/%d0%a5%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d1%96-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d1%96-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d1%96-%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%b4%d1%96-good-questions-and-good-answers). Дякую!

Comment: І все ж тут цікаві думки наведено.

Answer (score -2):

Я не науковець, але можливо я маю справжню відповідь на це питання. Телесик це повна несенітниця, при чому радянська. Маю екземпляр німецького перекладу українських казок 1921 року. Так от, там є казка, що починається один в один із Івасиком-Телесиком. От тільки в перекладі на українську вона називається «Іван, Богом даний». І взагалі в казках того часу, якщо довіряти перекладові, не рідко згадували Бога. В нас був глибоко віруючий народ. А от в Радянському Союзі Бога не було, дому Івасик-Телесик таки цілком може бути бовдурком, за прикладом «Івана дурачка» з російських казок.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до цього сайту! Зауважте, наші правила відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і соцмережах. Ми дійсно цінуємо відповіді, що ґрунтуються на поважних наукових (бажано, академічних) джерелах. Ба більше, запитання прямо вказує: *«Тому хотілося б дізнатися етимологію, яка **базується на поважних лінґвістичних джерелах**, а не на здогадках.»*. Ваш досвід аналізу однієї (неназваної?) книги є цікавою *здогадкою* і може стати частиною відповіді, але не її основою.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).